# How can I store user data?

Tags: android, database

I'm working on an Android app and I'd like to store user data (like name, city, state, email, etc.), a global scoreboard for everyone to see, and some geography data (to keep track of how many users are coming from which cities). I noticed that Android's built-in SQLite is really for local, on-device use, and not designed to keep global records on the back end. Is there a way to move the database onto a web host and use it on the back end instead of just for one device? Or do Android developers normally just go with a different language entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQLite is more ideal for storing local, on-device information. You don't want to store information for *all* of your users on each user's phone. You'll need a backend service, and there are many options.

[Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/) is a popular option.

[Parse](https://www.parse.com/) is much simpler than Amazon AWS, although you might find yourself limited if your app grows very large. For smaller apps, though, Parse takes care of all your backend headaches and provides a nice API for you to use.

If you want to do a lot of the work yourself you'll need a server to host it, some kind of server-side language to deal with requests from users, and a database (mySQL, Oracle, etc). This will be an enormous amount of work if you don't already know what you're doing, and I'd suggest going with a BaaS.

[Here](http://www.androidbegin.com/blog/list-best-android-backend-service-baas-provider/) is a list of other BaaS (backend as service) options.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(user, context, callback){
  user.user_metadata = user.user_metadata || {};
  user.user_metadata.displayName = user.user_metadata.displayName || "user";

  auth0.users.updateUserMetadata(user.user_id, user.user_metadata)
    .then(function(){
      callback(null, user, context);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      callback(err);
    });
}
```